# php - CURL HTTP Authentication at server side

Tags: php, xml, curl

i want to change xml value in php  but don't change ....

```
<?php

$url = "http://192.168.1.103:8080/ew.xml";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<DDCConfig:getValue xmlns:DDCConfig="urn:SMUDDCConfiguration">
<DDCConfig:Network>
 <DDCConfig:LocalIP>192.168.103.223</DDCConfig:LocalIP>
 <DDCConfig:GlobalIP>168.188.127.123</DDCConfig:GlobalIP>
<DDCConfig:RootBridge>Yes</DDCConfig:RootBridge>
</DDCConfig:Network>
</DDCConfig:getValue>';

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "lmk:alrud89");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array($xml));
$http_result = curl_exec($ch);
if($http_result){
echo $http_result;
}else{
echo curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

error message is

> * About to connect() to 192.168.1.103 port 8080 (#0) 
>   * Trying 192.168.1.103...
>   * connected
>   * Server auth using Basic with user 'lmk'
>   > PUT /ew.xml HTTP/1.1
>   > Authorization: Basic bG1rOmFscnVkODk=
>   > Host: 192.168.1.103:8080 Accept: */*
>   > Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   > Expect: 100-continue
>   < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   < Content-Length: 0
>   <
>   > WWW-Authenticate: Digest qop="auth", realm="mydomain.com",
>   nonce="1366254379"
>   * HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
>   * Closing connection #0

what is the problem & solution?

Comment: is there any thing listening on that ip?

Comment: One thing I can see right of the bat (not directly related to your auth error) is that you're not passing an associative array for the POST_FIELDS. Your POST data is XML, but it also needs to have a name.

Comment: @Dagon yes otherwise he would get error 404

Comment: @Dagon no...but i can see the data by firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your credentials are incorrect! (that's what error 401 means)

There's a wonderful plugin for Firefox called `poster` - install it and use it to double-check that the request is formatted correctly.

By the way, you might want to add the following header:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/xml"))
```

Another thing: PUT is not always supported, try POST - sometimes it'll work.

Comment: @user2235070 did you get the same response using poster ?

Comment: oh you were right . I change 'POST' instead of 'PUT'..it works!

Comment: Like AgilE said, try replacing `array($xml)` with `$xml`

Comment: you mean this part? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,array($xml));
i already did..not work...not change data...

Comment: @user2235070 in that case you need to debug it from the server-side, start with checking the server logs, see if there's any error. Did you add the content-type header like I showed ?

Comment: glad to have helped. how did you do it ?